# Extending Display WITHOUT plugging in monitor

Tags: display, hdmi

So with the current pandemic I'm WFH, but didn't manage to bring my monitor back from work. So far I've been plugging my macbook into the TV to extend the display, then using screen sharing on my personal macbook to view the second display. This is a bit of a pain as I have to have the HDMI cable trailing accross the room, considering I'm not actually using a display.

So basically, can I simulate an external display so it works exactly how it is at the moment, minus having to plug into the TV?

TIA.

Comment: What's your ultimate goal here? It's sounding a bit of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) to me. Why do you need to only see an extra display remotely? Why not just login over Remote Desktop as a different user & have your own display?

Comment: I just want it to extend the screen onto the second mac, so I can drag and drop between the two as you could if it was plugged straight into an external display

Comment: Drag & drop between 2 computers does not depend on having a second screen. You can just resize the remote if you can't see all of each at the same time. See pic - remote session shrunk to show between two local folders - [picture intentionally shrunk too small to read] https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkAnU.jpg

Comment: But currently I can't get the screen sharing to display something different than what is shown on the 'home' machine. When I plug a second display in, it gives me the option to show Display 1 or Display 2 (as below), but when I have no phyiscal display plugged in I don't have this option. Essentially, I just want to enable this option without physically plugging in a display which I'm not really using.
https://imgur.com/36LtBbo

Comment: Honestly, this makes no sense at all.  You’re plugging in a Mac to a TV that you actually don’t use and then use a different Mac to remote to it.  All this for drag and drop between two computers.  How about turning on file sharing and put those folders on your desktop?  That’s what it’s for

Comment: I know it doesn't make a huge amount of sense, but I'm currently developing a mobile app, so I need both the emulator and the IDE need to be run on the same machine

Comment: That’s not what you said, but regardless... they’re *not* running on one machine.  You’re connecting *remotely* to the other Mac where one of the apps is running.  It doesn’t make sense because you haven’t clearly identified your *objective* and listed your constraints. What do you ultimately need, not what you think will get you there?

Comment: Ok. I want to use my second macbook as an external display.

The method I've been using so far has been working well, minus having the cable across the room.

Comment: Then you need something like [Luna](https://lunadisplay.com/)